# loop view fields inside views-view--[view-name]--page.tpl

Tags: 7, views, theming

I'm within the template views-view--[view-name]--page.tpl and I want to fully style the fields within the templates. So I do var_dump($variables) and within this I can see all my nodes seem to be there, but there so deep within the structure it's impossible to see where exactly, plus this can't be the correct way to loop around it as I'd have a crazy long query!

So how do I simply loop around the view in the template I mentioned and get lets say the title and the body for the nodes in my view?

Comment: You can check how to render different parts of your view by looking at the default templates from the views module located under `sites/all/modules/views/theme/`. For instance if you where using `views-view.tpl.php` you would can print all nodes using `print $rows;`. You can then create another template `views-view-fields--[view-name]--page.tpl.php` to render all fields for a single node.

Comment: Yes, that's where I started but print $rows just seems to print the block out in the style within drupal dictates. I want to surround it with my own bootstrap html so would like to pick the fields, html and css from within a template file

Comment: On the edit screen for your view you can also check the template suggestions by clicking `advanced > theme information`. You should be able to add markup for a single field in the view by using the `views-view-field.tpl.php` template

Answer (score 1):

Use views-view-fields--.tpl.php and render the field with your custom markup

For example:

```
<div class="product-item">
    <div class="row clearfix">
      <div class="product-image"><?php print $fields['field_images']->content; ?></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row clearfix text-center">
      <div class="product-attributes"><?php print $fields['title']->content; ?></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row clearfix text-center">
      <div class="product-attributes"><?php print $fields['title_1']->content; ?></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row clearfix  text-center">
      <div class="product-attributes price"><?php print $fields['another_field']->content; ?></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks so to then embed this on the page within nodes template? I was using print views_embed_view('outputs','page'); but I don't think that would work for this

Comment: this will theme your view markup. So you can render your views as a block on a page or as a separate page

Comment: Just to follow up on @Shabir, don't embed views in a template. Use a block or other method like [preprocess hooks](https://www.drupal.org/node/223430).

Comment: ok cool think I'm getting my head around views now! So is there no way to get the field HTML. Basically what I want to do is attach some bootstrap button styling to a link to the node. I guess I could target it with js, but that seems a terrible idea!

Answer (score 0):

I noticed I never explained how I solved this, for anyone who comes across this. The best way I found of doing this was if you go into the view, under fields select the field you want to change and then choose rewrite results and then select 'Rewrite the output of this field'. You can see what tokens you can use by clicking 'replacement patterns'. If you want to mix and match different fields you select 'exclude from display' on each field but the bottom one in the list which will then make it available as a token within the last field on the list. Simples!